# Entity Framework Code First Transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4 with SqlServer CE as the database.

Because SqlServer CE does not support TransactionScope, so I have to resort to using BeginTransaction and RollbackTransaction method.

I have two GRUD functions to delete and create rows in the database.

What I want to achieve is something like this :

```
    using (var context = new MyContext())
                {
                    using (var tx = context.BeginTransaction()) 
                    { 
                       // grud functions
                       deleteRows();
                       addRows();

                       // do db stuff here... 
                       tx.Commit(); 
                    } 
                }
```

But I cannot find BeginTransaction in the context.

How can I go about it?

Comment: What prevents you from using the same context instance in `deleteRows` and `addRows`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a `grud` function?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I go about it

I think, you're misunderstanding a concept of `DbContext`. It is a local cache of entities + change tracker. Whatever you do with entities, this changes are just tracked by context without affecting underlying data source.

This all happens until you call `SaveChanges` method. This method applies changes from change tracker to data source in transaction manner, so, all of the changes you've made, will be consistent.

If you will write your `deleteRows` and `addRows` in a way, that they won't call `SaveChanges`, and put `SaveChanges` call somewhere outside these methods, you'll get desired transaction:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    // grud functions
    deleteRows(context);
    addRows(context);

    context.SaveChanges();
}

private void deleteRows(MyContext context) {}
private void addRows(MyContext context) {}
```

Comment: So I have to pass in context into the functions, because the crud function has it's own context.

Comment: @KevFixx: I you want your changes to be transactional, you have to use the same context instance for both functions.

Comment: Additionally [SaveChanges() runs as a transaction by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5660352/209259).

Answer (score 0):

In ObjectContext, `BeginTransaction()` is a method on Connection, not on the `ObjectContext`
<del>However, `DbContext` exposes `BeginTransaction` directly to the underlying connection. So possibly you aren't using a DbContext?</del>

Try

```
context.Connection.BeginTransaction()
```

Comment: context does not have Connection.

Comment: @KevFixx `ObjectContext` has [Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx), however DbContext doesn't have `BeginTransaction` - I was looking at a custom extension method :(