# Entity framework type of read lock

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

What is the default read lock for entity framework and how can i implement the repeatable read lock.

I am thinking that perhaps there is a global settings somewhere so that a readlock is acquired of type repeatable read by default then released once savechanges kicks in.

[What is the default transaction isolation level in Entity Framework when I issue “SaveChanges()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657145/what-is-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-in-entity-framework-when-i-issue) .Says here that the default isolation level is snapshot.How can i change to repeatable read.

Comment: You are confusing locks with transaction isolation levels. Besides, why do you think that you need a lock? It sounds like you are looking for pessimistic locking, a very bad practice for anything other than single user desktop applications. Optimistic concurrenty on the other hand, guarantees both correctnes and scalability

Comment: Or you may be trying to implement object versioning, or at least checkout functionality, through locks. You can't, because checking out a record for editing has nothing to do with locking - it's a higher level concept that's more complicated than locking. Use flags on the row itself or better yet, one or more separate tables with who checked out what

Comment: basically once i read from a row, i want to be sure nobody changes that row until my current transaction is complete.

Comment: Why do you think you need that? SaveChanges uses a transaction internally so you shouldn't worry about losing changes. If you want to use a long-running transaction as a quick-and-dirty checkout mechanism, you'll create scalability problems that can't be fixed. Locking rows while a user browses through a grid or goes for coffee is a sure way to prevent the application from serving even a couple of concurrent users.

Comment: In any case, EF *already* uses the Repeatable Read isolation level for transactions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657145/what-is-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-in-entity-framework-when-i-issue .Says here that the default isolation level is snapshot.How can i change to repeatable read.

Answer (score 1):

[Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) tells default isolation mode is database dependent. (2023 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions) does too, and has much better code examples.)

It also supply an example of how to handle transactions, which is what you need to benefit from what you likely want with isolation mode `repeatable read`. Beware, their example has a serious flaw, as it will swallow any exception.

Here is a fixed version of their example. `context` is supposed to be an instance of a class derived from `DBContext`.

```cs
using (var dbContextTransaction =
    context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
{
    try
    {
        // Your work here, then

        context.SaveChanges();
        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

As warned by Panagiotis Kanavos, this kind of locking should be avoided as much as possible. It reduces scalability, increases dead locks risks, may completely blocks other users as long as the transaction is running, ...

The `try catch rollback` could be considered superfluous, as disposing an ongoing `DbTransaction` causes it to rollback (and the `using` will ensures it gets disposed).