# How to get isolation level in EF for MSSQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, isolation-level

I am using EF for access MS SQL data with help LINQ. How can I get current isolation level ? For example this code:

```
var level = 
Database.Connection.UnderlyingTransaction.IsolationLevel.ToString();
```

give me error - `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

As I understand - UnderlyingTransaction is null because I don't use any transactions in my LINQ code.

Comment: UnderlyingTransaction is a property of connection.  What does that have to do with LINQ?

Comment: If you don't have a transaction, why do you need to isolation level?

Comment: @JamieRees - just need to understand can I read uncommited data or not ...

Comment: Maybe will help [What is the default transaction isolation level in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657145/what-is-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-in-entity-framework-when-i-issue)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin - I don't want to set level, I just want read a value

Comment: @MindSwipe - before today I was thinking the same way, but my log give me other information

Comment: @Alexander Oh s**t, I posted that comment on the wrong question, my bad. I have multiple open in my browser and this and another got me confused

Comment: @MindSwipe - anybody can make mistake - don't worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find how to get current isolation level with EF properties or methods , so we can use custom SQL query for that, for example like this:

```
public class UserOptionsMsSql
{
    [Column("Set Option")]
    public string SetOption { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

var resultsList = 
service.GetDataContext().Database.SqlQuery<UserOptionsMsSql>
("DBCC USEROPTIONS;").ToList();

var resultLevel =  resultsList[11] == null ? "unknown":resultsList[11].Value ;
```

Of course we can use any [other custom SQL scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038113/how-to-find-current-transaction-level) ...